# How can I place my button under an image and have it stay fixed when the window size changes?

Tags: html, css

Currently you can see on that the central image and the button underneath aren't grouped together which I would like them to be. Horizontally it spans fine but the button overlaps vertically onto the image depending on the window size. I would like the button to be in a fixed position directly underneath the image regardless of the window size.

You can see how I've placed the button underneath below. Can anyone see where I am going wrong? Cheers

Here is the relevant code

```
    html      {
         height: 100%;
         width: 100%;
    }

    body      {
         width: 100%;
         height: 100%;
    }

    #mainText {
         position: fixed;
         top: 35%;
         left: 33%;

    }

    #yesButton {
        position: fixed;
        top: 59%;
        left: 33%;
    }

    .image_off, #home:hover .image_on{
       display:none
    }
    .image_on, #home:hover .image_off{
       display:block
    }
```

================= HTML =================

```
<div id="mainText">
    <img src="images/mainText.png" height="160" width="340">
</div>

<div id="yesButton">
<a id="home"><img class="image_on" src="images/yesPlease.png" height="60" width="336" alt="" /><img class="image_off" src="css/images/yesPleaseHover.png" height="60" width="336" alt="" /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: I believe you need `position: absolute`, not `fixed`

Comment: I tried that, and it didn't change anything. The effect is still the same :/

Answer (score 0):

Pol is correct, position absolute is what you're looking for.

But you need to change more than just CSS in this case.

Wrap your div mainText around your yesButton div and make sure your yesButton's position is set to absolute.

```
</div>
<div id="mainText">
<img src="images/mainText.png" height="160" width="340">
<div id="yesButton">
<a id="home"><img class="image_on" src="images/yesPlease.png" height="60"   width="336" alt="" /><img class="image_off" src="css/images/yesPleaseHover.png"     height="60" width="336" alt="" /></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

You will also need to reposition the yesButton but I have a fiddle that shows a good indication of where you might want it.

https://jsfiddle.net/pjcscc2a/

Answer (score 0):

Moving the "yesButton" DIV into "mainText.png" and directly below the "maintext.png" image tag worked for me. I also had to comment out the CSS rule assigned to "yesButton"